# make a letter/number disappear when keyboard input matches the letter

Tags: java, keyevent

using a keyListener, as i pressed my keyboard the matching letter/number on the panel would disappear.i got the program running but it seems my keyListener isnt working at all. need help please.

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.util.*;

public class KeyEventSample extends JPanel{
Random r = new Random();
private String[] keyChar ={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0" };
static int win_h=600;
static int win_w=800;

public KeyEventSample() {
    addKeyListener( new KeyAdapter(){             
     public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
        for(int q=0;q<keyChar.length;q++){
            if(String.valueOf(e.getKeyChar()).toLowerCase()==keyChar[q]){

                keyChar[q]=" ";
                repaint();
            }   
        }
     }
  });
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for(int z=0;z<keyChar.length;z++){
        int x=r.nextInt(win_w-100);
        int y=r.nextInt(win_h-100);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        g.drawString(keyChar[z].toUpperCase(),x,y);
    }
}   

public static void main (String[] args) {
    KeyEventSample evnt = new KeyEventSample();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Key Event Example");
    frame.add(evnt);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(win_w,win_h);
    frame.setVisible(true);
 }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
if(String.valueOf(e.getKeyCode()).equalsIgnoreCase(keyChar[q]))
```

Comment: Mind explaining the logic behind comparing a number to an alphabetical String? http://ideone.com/77e6JE

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the logic in the `KeyListener`.

You are actually comparing a number to an alphabetical `String`.

For example, the keycode for 'a' is 65. In your `KeyListener`, you are really saying: is 65 equal to "a"? The answer will always be no.

What you want to do is take this:

```
private String[] keyChar ={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0" };
```

and make it into this:

```
private char[] keyChar = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0' };
```

Then, do this for the condition:

```
if(Character.toLowerCase(e.getKeyChar()) == keyChar[q]){
```

Comment: already tried doing that.. im think maybe the coordinates of the letters/numbers is involved in order to change its content.. but still i have no idea how to do that